# Julia significantly slower with @parallel

Tags: julia

I have this code(primitive heat transfer):

```
function heat(first, second, m)
    @sync @parallel for d = 2:m - 1
        for c = 2:m - 1
            @inbounds second[c,d] = (first[c,d] + first[c+1, d] + first[c-1, d] + first[c, d+1] + first[c, d-1]) / 5.0;
        end
    end
end

m = parse(Int,ARGS[1]) #size of matrix
firstm = SharedArray(Float64, (m,m))
secondm = SharedArray(Float64, (m,m))

for c = 1:m
    for d = 1:m
        if c == m || d == 1
            firstm[c,d] = 100.0
            secondm[c,d] = 100.0
        else
            firstm[c,d] = 0.0
            secondm[c,d] = 0.0
        end
    end
end
@time for i = 0:opak
    heat(firstm, secondm, m)
    firstm, secondm = secondm, firstm
end
```

This code give good times when run sequentially, but when I add @parallel it slow down even if I run on one thread. I just need explanation why this is happening? Code only if it doesn't change algorithm of heat function.

Comment: I'm not sure that parallel updating/reading different elements of a shared array really works.

Comment: @RezaAfzalan it should work ok if each participating process in the `SharedArray` only works on its local indices of the array. Has the OP looked at the [advection example](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/parallel-computing/#id2) from the parallel computing docs? I found it very helpful. Pay attention to the boundaries demarcated by `localindices`.

Comment: Unrelated to parallel computing, but a helpful habit to form early: in Julia, filling `firstm` and `secondm` by columns instead of rows is more efficient. Try putting `d` index in outer loop and `c` variable in inner loop.

Answer (score 8):

Have a look at http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/performance-tips/ . Contrary to advised, you make use of global variables a lot. They are considered to change types anytime so they have to be boxed and unboxed everytime they are referenced. This question also [Julia pi aproximation slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36967443/julia-pi-aproximation-slow) suffers from the same. In order to make your function faster, have global variables as input arguments to the function.

Comment: It solved my pi aproximation problem, but there are all variables in function parameters. As I said this runs smoothly but only without @parallel. And sorry I forgot to add iteration to heat(it should switch those matrixes). Edited

Comment: I think `@sync` is unnecessary and I have improvements without that. The loops does not carry a dependence to previous loops so just omit that.

Comment: After erasing @sync it doesnt return correct answer. Also warnings appeared. WARNING: Forcibly interrupting busy workers
WARNING: Unable to terminate all workers

Answer (score 2):

There are some points to consider. One of them is the size of `m`. If it is small, parallelism would give much overhead for not a big gain:

```
julia 36967257.jl 4
# Parallel:
0.040434 seconds (4.44 k allocations: 241.606 KB)
# Normal:
0.042141 seconds (29.13 k allocations: 1.308 MB)
```

For bigger `m` you could have better results:

```
julia 36967257.jl 4000
# Parallel:
0.054848 seconds (4.46 k allocations: 241.935 KB)
# Normal:
3.779843 seconds (29.13 k allocations: 1.308 MB)
```

Plus two remarks:

1/ initialisation could be simplified to:

```
for c = 1:m, d = 1:m
    if c == m || d == 1
        firstm[c,d] = 100.0
        secondm[c,d] = 100.0
    else
        firstm[c,d] = 0.0
        secondm[c,d] = 0.0
    end
end
```

2/ your finite difference schema does not look stable. Please take a look at [Linear multistep method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_multistep_method) or ADI/Crank Nicolson.