# Julia pi approximation slow

Tags: julia

I have pi approximation code very similar to that on official page:

```
function piaprox()
    sum = 1.0
    for i = 2:m-1
        sum = sum + (1.0/(i*i))
    end
end

m = parse(Int,ARGS[1])
opak = parse(Int,ARGS[2])

@time for i = 0:opak
    piaprox()
end
```

When I try to compare time of C and Julia, then Julia is significantly slower, almost 38 sec for m = 100000000 (time of C is 0.1608328933 sec). Why this is happening?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
julia> m=100000000 
julia> function piaprox()
           sum = 1.0
           for i = 2:m-1
               sum = sum + (1.0/(i*i))
           end
       end
piaprox (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @time piaprox()
 28.482094 seconds (600.00 M allocations: 10.431 GB, 3.28% gc time)
```

I would like to mention two very important paragraphs from [Performance Tips](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/performance-tips/#performance-tips) section of julia documentation:

> [Avoid global variables](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/performance-tips/#avoid-global-variables) A global variable might have its value, and
>   therefore its type, change at any point. This makes it difficult for
>   the compiler to optimize code using global variables. Variables should
>   be local, or passed as arguments to functions, whenever possible.....
>
> The macro [@code_warntype](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/performance-tips/#code-warntype) (or its function variant code_warntype()) can
>   sometimes be helpful in diagnosing type-related problems.

```
julia> @code_warntype piaprox();
Variables:
  sum::Any
  #s1::Any
  i::Any
```

It's clear from `@code_warntype` output that compiler could not recognize types of local variables in `piaprox()`. So we try to declare types and remove global variables:

```
function piaprox(m::Int)
    sum::Float64 = 1.0
    i::Int = 0
    for i = 2:m-1
        sum = sum + (1.0/(i*i))
    end
end
julia> @time piaprox(100000000 )
  0.009023 seconds (11.10 k allocations: 399.769 KB)
julia> @code_warntype piaprox(100000000);
Variables:
  m::Int64
  sum::Float64
  i::Int64
  #s1::Int64
```

**EDIT**

as @user3662120 commented, the super fast behavior of the answer is result of a mistake, without a return value LLVM might ignore the for loop, by adding a return line the `@time` result would be:

```
julia> @time piaprox(100000000)
  0.746795 seconds (11.11 k allocations: 400.294 KB, 0.45% gc time)
1.644934057834575
```

Comment: Note that the type annotations on `m` and `sum` aren't necessary for speed.

Comment: The type annotations (::Int, ::Float64), don't actually contribute anything to the performance here.  (Adding in useless type annotations is a common Julia mistake.)   Note also that you are forgetting to return the sum.  (LLVM might actually optimize away the whole loop!)